# Crear un Botón desde js

Tags: javascript

estoy creando una lista de compras desde js hacia html luego de apretar un botón y allí quiero crear un botón que me elimine esa lista, el código es el siguiente:

```
let guarda=document.getElementById('cargaDatosAg').addEventListener('click', function(){
  let producto =document.getElementById('cargaDatosProd').value
  let icono =document.getElementById('cargaDatosIcon').value
  let info =document.getElementById('cargaDatosIn').value
    if(producto == "") {
      alert('Debes ingresar un producto.');
      return;
    }    
  document.getElementById('cargaDatosProd').value = ""
  document.getElementById('cargaDatosIcon').value = ""
  document.getElementById('cargaDatosIn').value = ""

 let modelo =  `<li class = "list-group-item" data-producto = "${producto}" data-icono = "${icono}" 
 data-info = "${info}" data('eliminar', 'button')>
  <img src="${icono}" alt="${producto}" class="pantallaListadoIcono">${producto}</li>`
  listaCargada.innerHTML += modelo
  cargaDatos.hide()
  inicio.style.display = 'none'
  lista.style.display = 'block'
  listadoStorage.push(modelo)
  localStorage.setItem('listadoCompras', listadoStorage)
})
```

intenté varias cosas y nada me funcionó, soy nueva en js, gracias!!!

Comment: Hola Paula, Donde estas declarando la variable `cargaDatos` ?

Comment: hola, perdón estaba con otro proyecto, está mas arriba, así lo declaré:

Comment: var cargaDatos = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('cargaDatos'), {} )

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que te recomiendo es que utilices los constructores del document para crear de forma controlada los elementos HTML, por ejemplo para crear un button y añadirlo al div#principal (div con id principal) :

```
var button= document.createElement("button");
document.getElementById("principal").appendChild(button);
```

Luego para eliminar puedes usar el button que has creado y crear una función anonima que elimine el parent que te interesa ( en este caso el li)

```
button.onclick = function (){ 
           this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(this.parentElement.parentElement);
};
```

A continuación, te dejo un ejemplo del código

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Lista de compras</h1>
<ul id="cart">    
</ul>
<input type="number" id="nProd" value=1>
<input type="text"   id="textProd" value="Product">
<button id="addToCart" onclick="addToCartButtonClicked();">Añadir</button>

<script>
    function addToCartButtonClicked(){
        let number = document.getElementById('nProd').value;
        let text   = document.getElementById('textProd').value;

        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.textContent = "Remove";
        button.onclick = function (){
            this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(this.parentElement.parentElement);
        };
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.textContent= text+" | "+number;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.appendChild(p);
        div.appendChild(button);
        
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(div);
        document.getElementById("cart").appendChild(li);
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: no me estaría funcionando, yo quiero que me aparezca en el li, porque mi idea es que si ya compraste lo de esa lista se pueda borrar, no se si me explico bien, mil gracias por tu respuesta